Vite "rollup failed to resolve" build error xss
My project seems to work fine when building from GitHub Actions but when I imported to Azure DevOps I get the following error message. When I try adding xss to rollup options it just gives me another error. Any ideas?
vite v5.3.1 building for dev19...
transforming...
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: D:\ Available 149255.00 MB out of 153597.00 MB, Memory: Used 4148.00 MB out of 16383.00 MB, CPU: Usage 14.96%
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: D:\ Available 149255.00 MB out of 153597.00 MB, Memory: Used 4286.00 MB out of 16383.00 MB, CPU: Usage 14.23%
✓ 2495 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 11.00s
error during build:
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "xss" from "D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/vis-timeline@7.7.3_eae06edfa9dc55cb650c16630e7e2bbf/node_modules/vis-timeline/esnext/esm/vis-timeline-graph2d.js".## ##
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
build.rollupOptions.external
at viteWarn (file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1_sass@1.77.6/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:65810:17)
at onwarn (file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/@vitejs+plugin-react@4.3.1_vite@5.3.1/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.mjs:266:9)
at onRollupWarning (file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1_sass@1.77.6/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:65843:5)
at onwarn (file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1_sass@1.77.6/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:65505:7)
at file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18514:13
at Object.logger [as onLog] (file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20162:9)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19104:26)
at file:///D:/a/_work/1/s/project-app/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19062:26
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1.

Explicitly mark xss as an external dependency to avoid Rollup attempting to bundle it.
